# Magento 2: update multiple inventory with custom script by CSV

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Please help me that how we can update multiple inventory with custom script by CSV in magento 2.

Comment: Read csv and modify the inventory? Show your csv.

Comment: Yes I have did it.